# What is wrong with my function for counting names in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

This is part of a larger bit of code but I will include what I think is important. There are actually two types of linked lists I am working with. As you will see the first struct just links to the first node of the list.

Here's the first:

```
typedef struct mlist {
    Node *headFirstName;
    Node *headLastName;
} MultiLinkedList;
```

Here's the second:

```
typedef struct node {
    char *first;
    char *last;
    long number;
    struct node *nextFirst;
    struct node *nextLast;
} Node;
```

Here is how names and numbers are currently added to the list:

```
MultiLinkedList *add(MultiLinkedList *list, char *first, char *last, long num) {
    // allocate a new node
    Node *newNode = malloc ( sizeof(Node) );
    newNode->first = malloc ( strlen(first) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->first, first);
    newNode->last = malloc ( strlen(last) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->last, last);
    newNode->number = num;
    // add this new node at the head of the "byFirst" list
    newNode->nextFirst = list->headFirstName;
    list->headFirstName = newNode;
    // add this new node at the head of the "byLast" list
    newNode->nextLast = list->headLastName;
    list->headLastName = newNode;
    // return the multi-list object with updated head pointers
    return list;
}
```

And here is how I am currently attempting to count the names in the list:

```
int size(MultiLinkedList *list) {
    int count = 0;
    Node *newNode = malloc ( sizeof(Node) );
    newNode->nextFirst = list->headFirstName;
    newNode->nextLast = list->headLastName;
    while (newNode->nextFirst!=NULL) {
            count++;

    }
    // return the number of names in the list
    return count;
}
```

If there is a specific name for traversing multiple lists like this then could someone just direct me to that?

Comment: What is your specific problem? Can you be a little more explicit?

Comment: Your `add()` don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Strange design. Since `list->headFirstName = newNode;` and `list->headLastName = newNode;` both point to the same thing, it's not clear why you need two pointers instead of one.

Comment: I probably should have posted my main function but the reason that those seem to point to the same thing is for different functions that sort the list either by first name or last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should use `size_t` for **size**
- Your `malloc()` is useless
- If you don't do somewhere something like `x = x->next` how do you want your loop finish ?

---

```
size_t size(MultiLinkedList *list) {
    size_t count = 0;
    for (Node *i = list->headFirstName; i; i = i->next) {
        count++;
    }
    // return the number of names in the list
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is basic, you should read some book or some tutorial about list and C